# Magento 1.9.3 Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on boolean Payment/Model/Observer.php

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I am using Magento version 1.9.3 and payment gateway from CCAvenue.

At the time of checkout and sucessfull making the payment, when returning back to the website from CCAvenue. I am getting this error instead of successfull payment:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on boolean in app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php:46 Stack trace:
#0 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Mage_Payment_Model_Observer->salesOrderBeforeSave(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#1 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Payment_Model_Observer), 'salesOrderBefor...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#2 app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_order_sav...', Array)
#3 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(391): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_sav...', Array)
#4 app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(2117): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_beforeSave()
#5 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(316): Mage_Sales_Model_Order-> in app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php on line 46
```

So far, I googled for solutions and tried couple of things like below:

```php
$payment = $order->getPayment();
if(!isset($payment)) {
    return $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
}
```

With this solution, I am able to return to the checkout/cart but with the message of invalid access. Whereas the order is successfully done and the payment has deduction applied in all the cases.

I have also check the log but there is nothing that I can trace and rectify, FYI, here is the log relevant to it:

```
Stack trace:
#0 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Mage_Payment_Model_Observer->salesOrderBeforeSave(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#1 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Payment_Model_Observer), 'salesOrderBefor...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#2 app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_order_sav...', Array)
#3 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(391): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_sav...', Array)
#4 app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(2117): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_beforeSave()
#5 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(316): Mage_Sales_Model_Order-> in app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php on line 46
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when order object is not loaded correctly.
In this case "order id" from session is missing while loading order object.

In **CcavenuepayController.php**, response handler function

search for

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($session->getLastRealOrderId());
```

Replace with

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($response_array['order_id']);
```

We are replacing session order id with ccavenue response order id.